# Bootstrap carousel Images under static navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website:http://cyrusjan.com/

Under smaller resolution screens (mobile devices), my carousel images appear underneath the navbar. Any ideas on how to keep them stuck below the navbar? Also my 3rd image is smaller in length compared to my other 2 images. How do I keep my footer stuck underneath my carousel so there isn't any extra white space in between?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOTUd.png

Comment: where is your code? you have to post it in order to we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an offset to your #myCarousel element:

```
#myCarousel {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 51px;
}
```

Also, your navbar collapses for widths under 198px. I would set a min-width to your navbar and body to prevent that (but you could also use a media query to change your #myCarousel margin-top style to 101px).

```
body {
    min-width: 200px;
}

div.navbar {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

As for the footer, set its position to relative and remove the "bottom: 0;" style.

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #0072b1;
}
```

As for your images, you'll either have to resize them to all be consistent or make them scale to your container.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the slider going underneath the navigation bar, it should be noted that in full screen as well, it's the same. The solution is as follows:

```
#myCarousel {
  margin-top:51px;
}
```

Concerning the height of the 3rd image, the size (height and width) of your 3 images are not the same. In responsive mode, the slider will resize each image to fit the width. This can be fixed in your JavaScript setting for the carousel or by putting images of same width and height.